# How to run a batch file from android to remote PC

Tags: java, android, batch-file, networking

I would like to develop an app that clicks a button, run the batch file on a pc connected to the same network (for example ip: 192.168.1.80).

Looking for google did not find anything about it.

Is there a way to run a batch file on a pc using Android Java?

Thanks to everyone in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of options.

- Run a Java process on your destination pc and use socket communication.
- Start a webcontainer and talk to it via a Rest Api.
- A bit oldschool is RMI, but works quite easy.

Then use Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...) to run your batch file.

If you want to have some security, that's another story...

Answer (score 0):

You should make a server at remote pc that listens is any packet comes from your app, when that specific packet comes you can start the batch file, i dont see any problem.